# Enterasys S8 switch shows tbp port

Tags: switch, ethernet

When I see `sh port status` on Enterasys s8 switch, it given me list of tbp ports as follows:

```
tbp.0.1                       down     up                     other
tbp.0.2                       down     up                     other
tbp.0.3                       down     up                     other
tbp.0.4                       down     up                     other
tbp.0.5                       down     up                     other
tbp.0.6                       down     up                     other
```

what are these tbp ports?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The tbp port refers to a Tunnel bridge port, aka a GRE tunnel.